# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStagingAreaPub' of undefined

Tags: javascript

For the below code:

```
 document.getElementById ("ifrmWorkarea").contentWindow.document.all.hiddenfields.isStagingAreaPub.value == "Y")
```

I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isStagingAreaPub' of
>   undefined in chrome browser.

calling html:

```
<form  name="hiddenfields">
    <input type=hidden  name="isStagingAreaPub" value="<%= isStagingPub %>">    
</form>
```

Please suggest how to resolve this problem.

Comment: calling html:  
<form  name="hiddenfields">
  var isStagingAreaPub = 'Y';
  <input type=hidden  name="isStagingAreaPub" value="<%= isStagingPub %>">  
  
 </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that

```
document.getElementById ("ifrmWorkarea").contentWindow.document.all.hiddenfields
```

Does not even exist. So you can't retrieve that property from it because your selector was written incorrectly.

To find out what part of the selector is flawed in console write:

```
document.getElementById ("ifrmWorkarea").contentWindow
```

if that doesn't return undefined then write in console

```
document.getElementById ("ifrmWorkarea").contentWindow.document
```

and if that doesn't return undefined then write in console

```
document.getElementById ("ifrmWorkarea").contentWindow.document.all
```

Comment: document.getElementById ("ifrmWorkarea").contentWindow.document.form.getElementById("isStagingAreaPub").value == "Y"

Comment: Regardless if that is throwing the same error than something in your selector is selecting an undefined object.

Comment: Then you have now selected an object that exists but is null and trying to read the property of that which is impossible since it is null.